# standard feed locations?

Tags: php, rss, feed

I want to programmatically check if a site has feeds. How can I do that?

Are there standard feed locations?
Parsing the code for link tags with application/rss+xml attribute would be enough?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html) classes from Zend_Framwework. Zend_Feed::findFeeds does what you want.

Comment: Fantastic! Right under my eyes... Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Parsing the code for link tags with application/rss+xml attribute would be enough?

As far as I know, it is the *only* standard way to discover feeds. But that is no guarantee that you'll find them all.

Comment: Just to spare the next one the momentary confusion I had, we're talking about actualy `<link>` tags here, not `<a>` tags; and yes, as far as I know this is the standard way +1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [this resource](http://diveintomark.org/archives/2003/12/19/atom-autodiscovery) for information on discovering feeds. Replace "application/atom+xml" with "application/rss+xml" as necessary.